# ReadProcessMemory not working

Tags: c#, readprocessmemory

Basically this isn't returning all of the bytes I'm asking it to.

```
// ReadBytes Method
byte[] ReadBytes(uint address, int len)
{
    int bytesread = 0;
    byte[] output = new byte[len];
    ReadProcessMemory(HO_Handle, (IntPtr)address, output, len, out bytesread);
    return ouput; // by the time we get here, bytesread == 0x0031E000
}

// Call
byte[] region = ReadBytes(0x0C000000, 0x08000000);
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working and how I would go about fixing it?

Comment: Don't worry about my last answer.. Must be something else miscalculated.

Comment: Can you call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); after your ReadProcessMemory and tell me the return value? and check if ReadProcessMemory returns false.

Comment: ...and how have you declared `ReadProcessMemory`?

Comment: Xela, I checked and ReadProcessMemory returns false and Marshal.GetLastWin32Error returns 0.
reuben, yes I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found the cause as to why this isn't working but I restarted my PC and now it works fine. Windows must have been acting up for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong . The VB.NET code that I use, is like this

```
ReadProcessMemory(_targetProcessHandle, _mbi.BaseAddress, _byteBuff, _mbi.RegionSize, 0)
```

And I think you are not asking the right amount